# Offset in pagination of cosmosDb not supported in spring data cosmosdb library

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to get data by pagination from `CosmosTemplate.paginationQuery()`, but the problem is I am not getting data from the offset that I am setting in pagination object. Below is my code for setting pagination,

```
DocumentQuery documentQuery = new DocumentQuery(criteriaList, CriteriaType.AND));
if (Objects.nonNull(Offset) && Objects.nonNull(limit)) {
    PageRequest cosmosPageRequest = CosmosPageRequest.of(Offset, limit);        
    documentQuery.with(cosmosPageRequest);     
    Page<User> page = cosmosTemplate.paginationQuery(documentQuery, User.class, COLLECTION_NAME);
...
}
```

This always returns me list with first set of objects. So for example when I am setting offset as 11 and limit 10, it is always returning me records with offset 0 to 10. I tried to check library as well but there also no where they are setting offset while retrieving records. Below is the code for the same form azure-cosmosdb library `AbstractQueryGenerator.generateCosmosQuery()`.

```
    protected SqlQuerySpec generateCosmosQuery(@NonNull CosmosQuery query,
                                           @NonNull String queryHead) {
    final Pair<String, List<Pair<String, Object>>> queryBody = generateQueryBody(query);
    String queryString = String.join(" ", queryHead, queryBody.getFirst(), generateQueryTail(query));
    final List<Pair<String, Object>> parameters = queryBody.getSecond();

    List<SqlParameter> sqlParameters = parameters.stream()
                                                 .map(p -> new SqlParameter("@" + p.getFirst(),
                                                     toCosmosDbValue(p.getSecond())))
                                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());

    if (query.getLimit() > 0) {
        queryString = new StringBuilder(queryString)
            .append("OFFSET 0 LIMIT ")
            .append(query.getLimit()).toString();
    }

    return new SqlQuerySpec(queryString, sqlParameters);
}
```

Over here also hard coding for offset is done instead of taking from pagination object. Please can anyone suggest if I am doing anything wrong or getting records based on offset is not supported in this library.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in the azure-spring-data-cosmos SDK, where it does not honor the `OFFSET` as part of `CosmosPageRequest` and always set it to 0.
It is currently being investigated and will be fixed soon. Follow this issue for updates - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/28032

However, as a workaround for now, the best way would be to use a custom query using query annotation as mentioned in this example - Usage of offset - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-spring-data-cosmos-test/src/test/java/com/azure/spring/data/cosmos/repository/integration/ContactRepositoryIT.java#L235

Query annotation - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-spring-data-cosmos-test/src/test/java/com/azure/spring/data/cosmos/repository/repository/ContactRepository.java#L39